Process asyncio events in callbacks from within asyncio-unaware code?
I have a Python function foo, that actually is a layer of many functions, and makes regular callbacks to a Python function bar that I supply, like foo(bar). I also have an asyncio event loop running on the main thread, but the internals of foo are not aware of asyncio.
Now I have another thread running, that posts events to the event loop of the main thread. I want to use the callback bar to process those events. In other frameworks/languages, there are functions like processEvents in Qt, for example, that can be used to accomplish that, but I couldn't find anything similar for asyncio.
I've tried several things that I thought could work from my impression of the docs, like for example
def bar():
    asyncio.gather(*asyncio.all_tasks())

or
def bar():
    asyncio.sleep(0)

but the events posted from the other thread are still not being processed.

Disclaimer: Better software design would probably be to make foo use asyncio, but I'm looking for a solution for the case when I cannot make modifications to the code of foo.

mind telling more about what foo() does, and why it has to be center of operation - to me event loop that drives the call of foo in asyncio.to_thread() sounds kinda more sensible! Btw your example codes will never do anything because those are Functions that returns awaitable. Hence there's no action - awaitable need to be awaited to be scheduled and ran.

From your description this is pretty simple.  If foo() and bar() are unaware of asyncio, then you can't use them with asyncio.  That's all there is to it.  If foo() is a sync function, and you can't change it, and foo() calls bar(), you are done thinking about asyncio.  You can't use it.  (In any case, asyncio has potential benefit only when you have more than one Task, and while one Task is waiting for something another Task can execute.  You haven't described such a situation.)

bar needs to be an async function that will run in the event loop of the main thread, i.e. the event loop in which the tasks being awaited are running.
In your code you are using a call to asyncio.all_tasks, which returns only uncompleted tasks. Unfortunately, that would include by definition the callback task and so the callback task would be waiting for itself to finish and you would be waiting forever. I would suggest you add the tasks to be awaited to a tasks_to_be_awaited list as in the code below so we know precisely the tasks that we should await.
The trick is to use asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe to schedule your callback to run in the main thread's event loop.
import asyncio

tasks_to_be_awaited = []

def foo():
    ...
    future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(bar(), main_event_loop)
    future.result()  # Wait for callback to complete

async def bar():
    while tasks_to_be_awaited:
        task = tasks_to_be_awaited.pop()
        if not task.done():
            result = await task
            print(task.get_name(), result)

async def my_task():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 17

async def main():
    global main_event_loop

    # Make our event loop accessible to all threads:
    main_event_loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()  # loop for this thread

    # Create a task to be awaited by our callback bar:
    task = asyncio.create_task(my_task())
    tasks_to_be_awaited.append(task)

    # Emulate another, non-async thread running:
    future = main_event_loop.run_in_executor(None, foo)
    await future  # Wait for foo to complete

asyncio.run(main())

Prints:
Task-2 17

